# Can I call methods of anonymous classes in any time?

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class

I saw this sample code:

```
public class Main{ 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pocket<Object> pocket = new Pocket<Object>;
        System.out.println("test");
        pocket.put(new Object(){
            String field;
            void inner(){
               ...
            }
        });
    }  
}
```

Anonymous-classes doesn't have a class name. So I thought "How do I call anonymous class in any time?" while I'm reading this code.

As per title, Can I call methods of anonymous classes in any time? If I can, how do I call?

### PostScript

Object is **`java.lang.Object`**.

Comment: What do you mean by "any time" ? Also, 'Object' is your custom type ? not java.lang.Object, is it ? from ur code, it looks like that..

Comment: You want to be able to call the inner() method after getting it from the pocket, right? I don't thik there is a way to cast from the Object you will get to the anonymous inner class. So calling inner() would not be possible. Maybe with reflection. Interesting question, btw

Comment: Any time is for example, calling from others methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, anonymous classes are meant for providing implementations for a class within a method (or a block of code).

However, **they make the code harder to read/maintain** because of their verbosity.

For example, if you have an `interface` like `Product` as below:

```
public interface Product {
  void display();
}
```

In some other class, you can implement the `Product` `interface` as follows:

```
public class Test {

  public void static main(String[] args) {

     Product product = new Product() {

            @Override
            public void display() {
                //add your code to display

            }
        };

    //now using reference, you can call display()
    product.display();
}
```

}

Now, coming to your code, you can override `java.lang.Object` methods as shown below:

```
pocket.put(new Object(){

            @Override
             public String toString() {
                 return "My Object String";
             }

             //You can override other methods of java.lang.Object

             //note that, because your reference type is java.lang.Object, 
             //so you will NOT be able to call inner(), 
             // 'field' members even if you add them here
        });
```

> Can I call methods of anonymous classes in any time? If I can, how do
>   I call?

**You need the reference** to call the methods/members (as like any other object inocation) implemented through anonymous class so, `product.display();`will invoke the `display()` method. Or in your case, you can call like `pocket.get(i).toString()` or any methods of `java.lang.Object`

As a side note, remember that, in Java8, you can replace Anonymous classes with Lambda expressions provided you have only one `abstract` method to implement.